# Implementing Linked List in Kotlin

Tags: linked-list, kotlin

I've recently started learning Kotlin, so I decided to implement some data structures in it.
So, I've tried implementing a singly linked list:

```
package datastructures

public class LinkedList {
    private data class Node(var nodeValue: Int, var next: Node? = null)
    private var head: Node? = null

    fun insert(n: Int) {
        if(head == null) head = Node(n)
        else {
            var cur = head
            while(cur?.next != null) {
                cur = cur?.next
            }
            cur?.next = Node(n)
        }
    }

    fun print() {
        var cur = head
        while(cur != null) {
            print("${cur.nodeValue} ")
            cur = cur?.next
        }
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n = LinkedList()
    n.insert(5)
    n.insert(3)
    n.print()
}
```

and I got the following error:

```
Error:(22, 13) Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: cannot store to value org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.StackValue$OnStack@a0a447f
Cause: cannot store to value org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.StackValue$OnStack@a0a447f
File being compiled and position: (22,13) in C:/Users/Khaled/IdeaProjects/Kotlin/src/LinkedList.kt
PsiElement: cur?.next = Node(n)
The root cause was thrown at: StackValue.java:75
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:243)
    at org.jetbrains.jet.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:262)
    at ...
```

I've been searching here and in google but I can't figure out what's the problem causing this error

**Edit:**
So I've tried to re-implement the `insert` function and use `requireNotNull()` to avoid having the compiler worry about the null-safety stuff.

Here is the code and it's now working:

```
fun insert(n: Int) {
    if (head == null) head = Node(n)
    else {
        var cur = head!!
        while (cur.next != null) {
            cur = cur.next!!
        }
        cur.next = Node(n)
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin do you use?

Comment: @abacabadabacaba 0.8.11

Comment: Note:  the internal compiler error was due to a really old pre-beta version of Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
cur?.next = Node(n)
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what to do if `cur` is `null`. Currently, this results in internal error, but this may be [supported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1213) in a future version.

For now, the best solution is to rewrite the code such that the compiler could check that `cur` is never `null`. The problem is that the compiler assumes that fields declared as `var` can change at any time, so their values need to be loaded into local variables before checking for `null`:

```
var cur = head
if(cur == null) head = Node(n)
else {
    var next = cur.next
    while(next != null) {
        cur = next
        next = cur.next
    }
    cur.next = Node(n)
}
```

Comment: In Kotlin, you can use `!!` operator: `a!!` instead of `requireNotNull(a)`.